# How to extract frames at particular intervals from video using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, video, matlab-cvst

I am using matlab 2013a software for my project.

I face a problem while splitting video into individual frames.

I want to know how to get frames at a specific intervals from video.. i.e., i want to grab frames at the rate of one frame per second(frame/sec) .My input video has 50 frames/sec. In the code I have used **step()** to slice the video into frames.

The following is my code , basically a face detection code(detects multiple faces in a video) . This code captures every frame in the video(i.e 50fp approx) and processes it. I want to process frames at the rate of 1 fps. Please help me.

```
clear classes;
videoFileReader = vision.VideoFileReader('C:\Users\Desktop\project\05.mp4');
**videoFrame      = step(videoFileReader);**
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector(); % Finds faces by default
tracker = MultiObjectTrackerKLT;
videoPlayer  = vision.VideoPlayer('Position',[200 100       fliplr(frameSize(1:2)+30)]);

bboxes = [];
while isempty(bboxes)
  **framergb = step(videoFileReader);**
  frame = rgb2gray(framergb);
  bboxes = faceDetector.step(frame); 
end

tracker.addDetections(frame, bboxes);
frameNumber = 0;
keepRunning = true;

while keepRunning

   **framergb = step(videoFileReader);**
   frame = rgb2gray(framergb);

   if mod(frameNumber, 10) == 0
      bboxes = 2 * faceDetector.step(imresize(frame, 0.5));
      if ~isempty(bboxes)
        tracker.addDetections(frame, bboxes);
      end
   else
    % Track faces
    tracker.track(frame);
   end
end

%% Clean up
release(videoPlayer);
```

But this actually considers every frame. I want to grab 1fps.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I have successfully split the video into frames , the problem is I need some guidance for selecting a key frame out of 50 frames. I am new to matlab so i seek some assistance.

Comment: And this is my code for face detection . I need to process a video sample but the problem is since the video is 50fps the processing is very slow. So I thought of extracting 1 fps and try processing it     framergb = step(videoFileReader);
    frame = rgb2gray(framergb);
    bboxes = faceDetector.step(frame)  . This one actually considers every frame. I want to grab 1fps. Please guide me with the process

Comment: I have edited in that code snippet, as an attempt to help. On Stack Overflow, it is much better to show your code in the question (use the "edit" link under the question to make changes and improve your question). I am still not 100% clear on what the problem is, but I think someone else who knows more about Matlab video library could either understand already or ask you the right question to clarify what you are doing.

Comment: I have shared my entire code. Please check whether you can help. To be clear, the code captures each frame from the input video and process each of the frame to detect faces. now the problem is if the input video is 50fps , that is causing the processing speed to go down. So i wanted to capture only 1fps and process that frame to detect faces.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out , I have done all the corrections and I also have highlighted the parts which needs assistance . Probably, i guess at least by now you should have an understanding of what exactly the problem is.

Comment: http://in.mathworks.com/help/imaq/framegrabinterval.html   This is the feature exactly i want but it is not avilable in matlab 2013a. I want some assistance in performing this manually through code.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done directly in Matlab 2013a, because the video access library does not provide the feature you want. Writing the necessary code to implement an efficient frame skipping routine is not really possible using just Matlab code (you would need to look inside the video libraries)

Working around it, you have two basic options:

1. Do as little work as possible on frames that you do not want to process.

Where you currently have

```
framergb = step(videoFileReader);
```

Instead do something like

```
for i=1:49,
  step(videoFileReader);
end
framergb = step(videoFileReader);
```

(NB this does not allow for going beyond end of input)

2. Pre-process your file with a tool like `ffmpeg`, and reduce the frame-rate before you use Matlab.

The `ffmpeg` command might look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i 05.mp4 -r 1 05_at_1fps.mp4
```

Comment: Plus 1 - I personally would choose `ffmpeg` as well.